# how to create web wallet for bitcoin

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, bitcoind, wallet.dat

I want to create a web wallet for bitcoin in which anyone can create their account and do the transactions but my node allow me to create one desktop wallet only. so i am not getting how this webwallet will work for multiple users.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin core does not support multiple users with separate addresses in a single wallet.

Neither does it provide for running a wallet service to other people.

Comment: Although, it could be used for one but, your backend and not Bitcoin Core will have to handle the details of user balances and transactions between users.